# Ruby on Rails 5 Action Mailerのエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Rails でWebサイトの開発をしています。
/config/environments/development.rbで下記のコードを記述するとエラーが発生します。

```rb
config.aciton_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
port: 587,
authentication: :plain,
user_name: Rails.application.secrets.SMTP_EMAIL,
password: Rails.application.secrets.SMTP_PASSWORD
}
```

エラーメッセージは次の通りです。

```
>｀method_missing': undefined method｀ aciton_mailer'
```

使用用途としては、Devise Gemを使用した認証システムを構築しており、メールアドレス・ユーザ名の簡易なユーザ認証をしたのちにメールを飛ばし、本登録するというシステム設計の予定です。

現状は、何かしらの原因でaction_mailerが起動しなかったことがわかるのですが、Google検索にかけてもRubyやRailsのバージョンの違いじゃないかという指摘しか見つけられず何が原因かわかりません。

こんな観点で考えてみたら解決に繋がるのでは?というアイデアでも構いませんので、ご教示お願いします。

次の通り、Gemfileを作成しています。

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4', '< 0.6.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
 # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
 gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
 # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
 gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
 gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
 # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
 gem 'spring'
 gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
 gem 'better_errors'
 gem 'binding_of_caller'
 gem 'pry-byebug'
 gem 'pry-rails'
 gem 'overcommit'

 gem 'annotate'
end

group :test do
 # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
 gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15', '< 4.0'
 gem 'selenium-webdriver'
 # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
 gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

#Use user configration framework
gem 'devise'

gem 'bootstrap'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'popper_js'
gem 'tether-rails'

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

#### バージョン情報

Ruby 2.5.1
Rails 5.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aciton_mailer がスペルミスです。 action_mailer で解決すると思います。

Comment: 瞬殺ですね。 すばらしいです。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます!スペルミスは最初に疑ってなんども見直しましたが見落としていました。無事rails serverが動くようになりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

> ｀method_missing': undefined method｀ aciton_mailer'

本来あるはずの`action_mailer`というメソッドが定義されていないというエラーであるため、
[`method_missing': undefined method`action_mailer' for ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894467/method-missing-undefined-method-action-mailer-for-railsapplicationcon)の回答にあるように、gemの再インストールを試してはいかがでしょうか?

手順

1. Gemfile.lock を削除
2. bundle install

Comment: 共有ありがとうございます。Gemfile.lockの削除をして bundle installを再度行いましたが、やはり同様のエラーが出るようです。Gemfileを質問に改めて記載しますので、より詳細にお伝えいただけると幸いです.

Comment: @Takuya すみません。外していたようですね。念のため確認ですが https://github.com/RailsApps/learn-rails/blob/master/config/environments/development.rb#L45 にRailsのサンプルソースがあるのですが、config.action_mailer はこのリンク先と同様に`Rails.application.configure do`ブロック内に定義されていますか?

Comment: `development.rb`ファイルを確認し、`Rails.application.configure do`ブロック内部で定義されていることは確認できました.

Comment: @Takuya 2点確認です。バージョンは違うと思いますが、 https://github.com/RailsApps/learn-rails/blob/master/Gemfile.lock#L8 のようにGemfile.lock内に`actionmailer`の記載はあるでしょうか?

Comment: @Takuya もう1点は、ターミナルを開いて、railsのプロジェクトディレクトリ内で`bin/rails console`とした場合にも同様のエラーが出るでしょうか?

Comment: ありがとうございます.Gemfile.lock内部に`actionmailer`の記載はありました.`actionmailer (5.2.0)`と記載されてました.
また,ターミナルでrailsのプロジェクトディレクトリで`rails c`を実行したいところ同様のエラーが出ました.

Comment: @Takuya 念のため確認ですが、`bin/rails c`もしくは`bundle exec rails c`でも同様のエラーが出るでしょうか?

Comment: `bin/rails c` でも `bundle exec rails c`でも同様にエラーが出ます

Comment: @Takuya お手数をおかけしました。役に立てずにすみません。原因不明ですね。